# Retriving a document with a small array in mongodb slow?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, atlas

I have an express node app where I have a database with about 10000 documents in a collection which I run on an Atlas M2 Instance. Each document have 25 fields where 4 fields are of type array (3 contain numbers and the 4th is mixed). The biggest array contains 168 number. When I query for say 100 documents WITHOUT any of the array fields it takes about 200ms seconds to retrieve the data. But if I add the 4 array fields to the data I want to retrieve, the query takes about 4-5 seconds. But then if I for reasons of debugging do a lot of queries in a short while, then all of I sudden on rare occasions the queries (all) can go down to about 300ms and stay so for a couple of hours.

The search query is not done on the array field so there is no searching or sorting of the arrays.

Since there is so little data i each array I can not understand what the problem is, is it because of the instance type I am using?!

What could be the problem?

Comment: Are you getting throttled? "M0 free clusters and M2/M5 shared clusters limit the total data transferred into or out of the cluster in a rolling seven-day period. The rate limits vary by cluster tier as follows:
...
* M2: 20 GB in and 20 GB out per period
...
Atlas handles clusters that exceed the rate limit as follows:
* Atlas throttles the network speed of the cluster."  https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/reference/free-shared-limitations/

Comment: Try downloading MongoDB compass and running an "explain plan" see what it spits out as what is taking long

Comment: I am not getting throttled, I am well below the limit. Just because I wrote this question, all of a sudden the speed increase is there again, just randomly. I assume it will return to its slower speed at some point. I checked the query with compass, its lightning fast, as I imagine it should be. Thinking out loud, I wonder if there is something going on with mongoose, express, or node. But when the speed increase or decrease happens, it affects both my local development code as well as the production code I am running at render.com in the same moment.